# Better way to empty all the values of an object by setState in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am using React. This is my state

```
state = {
customerData: {
      id: '',
      name: '',
      type: '',
      place: '',
      country: '',
      timezone: 'GMT+5:30',
      status: false
    }
}
```

There is an edit functionality where the **customerData** object gets populated on click of edit button. I am showing this data in a modal.

Now in the modal, when I click the submit button, the modal should hide and the data populated in the **customerData** object should be empty. I can do it like this:

```
this.setState({
customerData: {
      ...this.state.customerData
      id: '',
      name: '',
      type: '',
      place: '',
      country: '',
      timezone: '',
      status: false
    }
}
})
```

I am wondering is there any one line way in ES6 to make the **customerData** Object empty. Because, if there are too many fields, it will be difficult.

Answer (score 2):

There are two easy options here:

## Create a default object

Above your component you can create the 'empty' value for your state. For example:

```
const emptyCustomerData = {
  id: '',
  name: '',
  type: '',
  place: '',
  country: '',
  timezone: '',
  status: false,
}
```

When you want to clear your state object, now you just call:

```
this.setState({
  customerData: emptyCustomerData,
})
```

---

## Allow all the values of `customerData` to be nullable

You could simply set `customerData` to an empty object:

```
this.setState({
  customerData: {},
})
```

Doing this means that before using any of the properties in your code, you need to check for `undefined`:

```
// This sets myVal to customerData.name, or if name is undefined, to an empty string
const myVal = this.state.customerData.name || ''
```

Comment: `this.state.customerData?.name`

Answer (score 2):

You can set a variable like **initialState**:

```
const initialState = {
  customerData: {
      id: '',
      name: '',
      type: '',
      place: '',
      country: '',
      timezone: 'GMT+5:30',
      status: false
  }
}
```

And before you hide the modal, do a:

```
this.setState(initialState)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to preserve the `customerData` keys, for your use case it may be sufficient to set everything to null which would simplify the reset:

`this.setState(customerData: Object.assign(...Object.keys(this.state.customerData).map(k => ({[k]: null}))))`

https://jsfiddle.net/0ymx7fsq/

Alternatively, since you're using class components you can also save the initial state in a constructor as well:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = initialState;
}
...
reset() {
    this.setState({ customerData : initialState.customerData });
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce in order not to rely on params count and number. It should looks like this

```
const data = {
  id: '1',
  name: '2',
  type: '3',
  place: '4',
  country: '5',
  timezone: '6',
  status: true
}

function getDefaultObject(obj) {
  const defaultValues = {
    'string': '',
    'boolean': false
  }

  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, rec, index) => {
    return { ...acc, [rec]: defaultValues[typeof obj[rec]]}
  }, {})
}

console.log(getDefaultObject(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just facing your problem today and i solved it with this code

```
const handleResetState = () => {
    const {customerData} = this.state
    let emptyState = {};
    for (const key in customerData){
        emptyState = {...emptyState, [key] : ""}
    }
    //i think you will more need the second option, so dont use first option
    //normal change (first option)
    this.setState({customerData: emptyState});
    //in case if your key need to have special initial value that are not empty string (second option)
    this.setState({customerData: {...emptyState, status: false} })
}
```